# Store a language dictionary in MySQL: Handling multiple definitions

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary, database-design, normalization

I'm currently moving a flat database file to MySQL and I've come to quite a challenge in regard to how to structure it correctly. The goal is to look-up a Japanese word and output definitions in JSON.

**How can I best represent this data in MySQL?**

### Flat file Structure

The current flat-file is:
word+ [reading*]/(verb/noun/adjective)/definition+/uid

Here are some sample entries,

> 螠(oK) [ゆむし;ユムシ] /(n) (uk) spoonworm (esp. species Urechis unicinctus)/EntL2265440/
>
> 蠔油(oK) [ハオユー] /(n) (obsc) (uk) (See オイスターソース) oyster sauce (chi: haoyou)/EntL2232860X/
>
> 袘 [ふき] /(n) (obsc) turned-back hem of a kimono/EntL2566160/
>
> 襅(oK) [ちはや] /(n) (obsc) (uk) thin, white ceremonial haori worn by miko/EntL2222620X/
>
> 跑(oK) [だく] /(n) (abbr) (See 跑足) trot (as in horse riding)/EntL2110610X/
>
> 踠き(oK) [もがき] /(n) (uk) struggle/writhing/wriggling/floundering/EntL2656220/

As you can see, some words have many 'readings', some have many 'types'.

This might seem strange but basically as the target language is Japanese the same 'word' can have multiple ways of writing it, as well as multiple or no 'readings' (this isn't included if the reading is the same as the word) and definitions.

Compounding this is that words can simultaneously be a verb or a noun amongst other things. I can't use a single field and just select one type.

### Challenges

The main problem here is of course database normalization. The standard idea would be to create a table for readings and definitions and link them to the main 'definitions' table using a foreign key. But this very quickly gets out of hand when you also consider that the flat file has many types of word type (it's not only verbs, nouns, adjectives, but also idioms, interjections and such) - should those be their own tables too or should I create 20 fields in each table row such as isVerb isAdjective? Seems messy.

Part of me just wants to break normalisation and store all the English definitions in a single varchar field... is that so bad?

In summary, is normalisation always required? In a situation like this with so much multiplicity and so many optional fields, what's the best thing to do?

Could any DB guru's point me in the right direction?

Comment: Make a table whose key is `(word, reading, type)`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help me understand what you want to do.  Data structures should be driven by how the data is going to be used.

Comment: @Barmar, That's my goal. But a table can have multiple readings words, types and definitions. Hence the problem.

Comment: The primary key will be `UID`. You can then have duplicates of `(word, reading, type)` if a word has multiple meanings.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar and his `INDEX(word, reading, type)` and the potential for some words to be repeated, some readings to be repeated, and multiple types for a word.  As for "normalization" -- It is not the "be all, end all"; it is just a textbook suggestion.  This seems like a case where it does not apply.  You may need other INDEXes, depending on the SELECTs you will have.

Answer (score 0):

You create one additional `types` table with a `word_type` column and a foreign to the main `words` table.
Then an entry in the `words` table could be referenced by multiple rows in the `types`table.